# Is there a way to specify cloudformation stack deletion policy using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have created a VPC using CDK, and now have a need to change the number of subnets and NAT gateways without destroying the (now in production) ec2 instances in it or the (now in production) EIPs that are whitelisted in other systems.

I tried this using CDK and it tried to destroy the VPC and re-provision everything, which is undesirable in production.

Since it is apparently not possible to do what I want by changing the stack definition, I need to get rid of the stack, without removing the VPC.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.RemovalPolicy.html

I found this document here about a RemovalPoliy enum in CDK, but there is nothing saying where that can be applied.  Google searches resulted in only references to S3 and RDS, even though this enum is in CDK core.  I tried applying it to the following CDK resources: stack, vpc, security group, etc, but none of those constructs accept the removalPolicy parameter.

eg:

```
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'PRODVPC', {
  maxAzs: 2,
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN
});

new VPCPRODStack(app, 'RDVPCPRODStack', {
  env: {region: 'ca-central-1', account: '12345'},
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN
});
```

What am I missing?  Is it even possible to set a cloudformation removal policy using CDK at the stack level?

Comment: Can you show some code how you "tried applying it to the following CDK resources: stack, vpc, security group, etc, but none of those constructs accept the removalPolicy parameter."? Any error messages

Comment: I've updated the question to show the places I'm trying to use it.  This is the type of error you would get because the construct simply does not accept that property.
`error TS2345: Argument of type '{ env: { region: string; account: string; }; removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StackProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'removalPolicy' does not exist in type 'StackProps'.`

Comment: discussed here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12563

Comment: FYI, there actually is a way to update VPC subnets after initial deployment, albeit it’s a bit hacky. You can associate secondary CIDR block with VPC using CfnVPCCidrBlock construct and then create new Subnet construct using that cidr block.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one you're requesting for is https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/72

For now

- You can define a custom resource backed by lambda which calls cloudformation set-stack-policy  api and updates policy.
- You have https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnResource.html#apply-wbr-removal-wbr-policypolicy-options which you can use to applyRemovalPolicy i.e to either destroy or retain.

ex: If I want to apply destroy policy to all my cfnresources

import { CfnResource, IAspect, IConstruct, RemovalPolicy } from '@aws-cdk/core';

apply_destroy_removal_policy_aspect

```
export class ApplyDestroyRemovalPolicyAspect implements IAspect {
  public visit(construct: IConstruct): void {
    if (CfnResource.isCfnResource(construct)) {
      construct.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
    }
  }
}
```

and apply it on all the resources by a stack

```
const destroyResourcesAspect = new ApplyDestroyRemovalPolicyAspect();

core.Aspects.of(safetyStack).add(destroyResourcesAspect));
```

This I've seen lot of people using to ensure it destroys any resources created as part of Personal Stacks in CDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
vpc.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
```

...

```
 // Create a VPC
    this.vpc = new aws_ec2.Vpc(this, `MyAppVpc${props?.env}`, {
      ipAddresses: aws_ec2.IpAddresses.cidr('10.0.0.0/16'),
      defaultInstanceTenancy: aws_ec2.DefaultInstanceTenancy.DEFAULT,
      maxAzs: 1,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          name: 'PublicSubnetA',  created
          subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'PrivateSubnetA',
          subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        },
      ],
    });
    this.vpc.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
```